Measure each delay using pyVISA using mdo32 tektronix
I'm trying to automatically measure (using pyVISA) the delay between each occurrences of the specified Mid reference crossing of two waveforms.
I can do it manually with cursers as shown below (for second delay) , but I can't find a way to do it automatically through pyVISA.
Any idea how to do that?
Thanks in advance

